# order by StudentId in query using cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.0

hello i am trying to order data through query.
i checked many documentation but their having DESC and ASC.
i want order through my decided number like.

---

```
    $bb = $this->StudentsTest->find('first', 
         array('conditions' => array('StudentsTest.custom_test_title' => $customTestId, 'StudentsTest.test_id' => null, 
'StudentsTest.student_id'  => array_values($result)),
'order' => array('StudentsTest.student_id' =>  array_values($result))));

     print_r($bb);
     exit();
```

**array_values($result) = (40,35,47,25,55,30);**

but they give me  output through asending number. please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
$this->set('studentTests', $this->StudentsTest->find('all', array('conditions' => array('StudentsTest.custom_test_title' => $customTestId, 'StudentsTest.test_id' => null, 'StudentsTest.student_id'  => $result),'order' => 'FIELD(StudentsTest.student_id, '.implode(',', $result).')',)));
```